# Exclude post ID from wp_query

Tags: wp-query, exclude

How can I exclude one specific post from a WP_Query query? (For example, show all posts apart from a post with the ID 278)

I've tried the post__not_in argument but it just removes all posts..

Any help would be great.

Here is my current query

```
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'case-study',
        'paged' => $paged,
    ));
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose this was heavy, but to answer your original question, I've collected all of the posts id's in an array in the first loop, and excluded those posts from the second loop using **'post__not_in'** which expects an array of post id's

```
<?php
$args1 = array('category_name' => 'test-cat-1', 'order' => 'ASC');
$q1 = new WP_query($args);
if($q1->have_posts()) :
$firstPosts = array();
    while($q1->have_posts()) : $q1->the_post();
        $firstPosts[] = $post->ID; // add post id to array
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo "<h2>" . get_the_title() . "</h2>";
        echo "</div>";
    endwhile;
endif;
/****************************************************************************/
// array of post id's collected in first loop, can now be used as value for the 'post__not_in' parameter in second loops query $args
$args2 = array('post__not_in' => $firstPosts, 'order' => 'ASC' );
$q2 = new WP_query($args2);
if($q2->have_posts()) :
    while($q2->have_posts()) : $q2->the_post();
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo "<h2>" . get_the_title() . "</h2>";
        echo "</div>";
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

The first loop displays all posts in a category, and collects the post id's into an array.

The second loop displays all posts, excluding posts from the first loop.

Comment: On another note, Is there a way to add wp-pagenavi to the 2nd query?

Comment: In case you ever revisit your answer: Please fix your code markup/intending. Thanks.

Answer (score 90):

The parameter you are looking for is `post__not_in` (kaiser has a typo in his answer). So the code could be like:

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post__not_in' => array(278),
    'post_type' => 'case-study',
    'paged' => $paged,
));
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); endwhile;
```

[WP_Query post__not_in documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: You know, there are [edit]s for correcting typos :)

Comment: @Ziki the comma in the array is not a typo it is valid PHP syntax, if thats what you mean.

Comment: @leonziyo - no, he originally had there "posts__not_in" instead of "post__not_in", see history of his answer. Coma is fine

Comment: @Ziki I am not sure if I would appreciate a _coma_ :D

Answer (score 20):

You have to define the `post__not_in` arg as array. Even for a single value. And please don't overwrite global core variables with temporary stuff.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'    => 'case-study',
    'paged'        => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => array( 1, ),
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    // do stuff

} // endwhile;
} // endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative codes;

## Exclude category posts

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts');
function exclude_category_posts( $query ) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set('cat', array( -22, -27 ));
    }
}
```

## Remove posts from homepage page

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_remove_posts_from_home_page');
function wpsites_remove_posts_from_home_page( $query ) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set('category__not_in', array(-1, -11));
    }
}
```