# How to exclude posts for current user

Tags: query, user-meta, posts-where

How can I hide posts that are in an array of ids in the `usermeta` for the current user in the `main query`.

I can use `post__not_in` in `meta_query` but I do not know which option to use for only a specific user.

I think should use `posts_where`?

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: I searched the entire site but found nothing. I can not think of anything :/

Comment: And you haven’t found this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65146/exclude-post-id-from-wp-query which is first result in Google for query “WordPress exclude posts from loop”? Seriously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude post ID from wp\_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65146/exclude-post-id-from-wp-query)

Comment: Really? The problem is that I want to hide only for the current user (logged in).

Comment: So what’s the problem? ‘get_current_user_id()’, ‘is_user_logged_in()’, or ‘get_user_meta()’?

Comment: I do not know how to do the ids query.

Comment: so please, update your question, show us, that you’ve done any research and tried to solve it, before asking question - it’s Q&A site and not “do it for me, because I don’t want to search” site... Because the question in its current state is just a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, because you've already mentioned all the tools that you need to solve it...

Just use `pre_get_posts` filter, check if the user is logged in, get the IDs of posts he should not see and exclude them in query:

```
function remove_some_posts_for_user( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $posts_to_remove_for_current_user = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'posts_to_remove', true );
        if ( ! empty($posts_to_remove_for_current_user) is_array($posts_to_remove_for_current_user) ) {
            $query->set( 'post__not_in', $posts_to_remove_for_current_user );
        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_some_posts_for_user' );
```